# How do I share photos between two MacBook Pros wirelessly?

Tags: mac, laptop, macbook, wireless-networking, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I share files between two Macs wirelessly?](https://superuser.com/questions/171053/how-do-i-share-files-between-two-macs-wirelessly)

How do I share photos between two Macbook Pro laptops?

I want to download photos from my other MacBook Pro; how do I go about doing that without cables (ie. transfer from one to the other wirelessly)?

I have the same question as [this girl](http://www.thewinforums.com/threads/52858-How-do-i-share-photos-between-two-macbook-pro)... Thanks!

Comment: The other question is close to an exact duplicate. I recommend closing this one since the other is more general and will help more users.

Comment: The answers are completely different, though. Sharing photos assumedly means iPhoto--all the user has to do is activate the photo sharing preference on one of the computers and then use the other computer to drag the photos from the remote library to the local one. Bonjour takes care of the hard stuff. This is NOTHING like using AFP like what the "duplicate" question is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1549

but I prefer using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) it is really convenient (like having a hard drive over the net).

Comment: this answer is general too...I would suggest deleting duplicate

Comment: Nice link to the kb article. Post this answer over on the the duplicate article and I'll vote it up.

Comment: Ok it is done...!