# How do I share files between two Macs wirelessly?

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, file-sharing

How do I share files between two Macs wirelessly?

This is the more general version of my [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/171045/how-do-i-share-photos-between-two-macbook-pros-wirelessly)...

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. I'm voting to close the other question since this more general question has more potential to be helpful to others.

Comment: @Doug - surprisingly we didn't have a "file sharing between two Macs" question, yet. I closed the other question for this one, more general, indeed.

Comment: I was surprised as well. Many about networking Mac & PC, but none so basic as this.

Answer (score 3):

On each of the computers:

1. Go to System Preferences app.
2. Choose "Sharing".
3. Check "File sharing". Read the instructions about permissions there to ensure that you'll be able to do what you need to do.

When you open a new file browsing window in Finder, you should see the other computer listed. Click on the other computer and you will be able to view, copy, etc.

Note that this will only work if the two computers are on the same subnet - if they're both connected to the same wireless access point or router, you should be ok.

Comment: As long as the two computers are on the same subnet, of course.

Comment: Good point, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1549

but I prefer using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) it is really convenient (like having a hard drive over the net).

Comment: +1 for dropbox - it also gives you a backup

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out [AirDrop](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#airdrop).  If it works for your needs and you have the correct requirements it is a simple way to share files wirelessly between computers.

Details about using it and system requirements can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4783)

Comment: not available Lion and below though